# snap selection to week/month/year

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I'm using Vega Lite in a crossfiltery app with an external data source.

I'd like the selection on a chart with a temporal scale to "snap" or "round" to a time interval which I'll supply in the spec.

I don't see anything about this in the [selections documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/selection.html), so I guess I will probably need to generate a Vega spec from the Vega Lite spec, and then patch it. That's not something I've done yet, but I'm eager to learn.

However I am surprised not to find this question on SO, GitHub or Slack. I think I've searched for all combinations of {vega, vega-lite} x {round, snap}.

Closest I can find is [an issue related to snapping selections for ordinal scales](https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/958).

Am I using the wrong terminology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue regarding snapping ordinal scales is more about snapping to time intervals, and [this comment by Jeff Heer](https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/958#issuecomment-320416356) covers the topic thoroughly.

The resulting Vega expressions are lengthy, but the process is straightforward:

> 1. Get the x-coordinate value.
> 2. Run it through a scale inversion (`x.invert`) to map from pixel domain to data domain.
> 3. Perform "snapping" by rounding / truncating values in the data domain.
> 4. Re-apply the x scale to get the snapped pixel coordinate.

We can change the `update` fields of the `signals` to implement this truncation.

#### snap to year

Say the selection is named `selection1`. Vega-Lite will generate a Vega spec including the signal `selection1_x` (redacted for brevity):

```
{
  "name": "selection1_x",
  "value": [],
  "on": [
    {
      "events": {
        "source": "scope",
        "type": "mousedown",
        "filter": // ... 
      },
      "update": "[x(unit), x(unit)]"
    },
    {
      "events": {
        "source": "scope",
        "type": "mousemove",
        "between": // ...
      },
      "update": "[selection1_x[0], clamp(x(unit), 0, width)]"
    },
    // ...
```

We can replace the `x(unit)` expressions in the first `on` item, and the `clamp(x(unit), 0, width)` expression in the second `on` item, using the steps above:

```
{
  "name": "selection1_x",
  "value": [],
  "on": [
    {
      "events": {
        "source": "scope",
        "type": "mousedown",
        "filter": // ...
      },
      "update": "[scale(\"x\",datetime(year(invert(\"x\",x(unit))),0)),scale(\"x\",datetime(year(invert(\"x\",x(unit))),0))]"
    },
    {
      "events": {
        "source": "scope",
        "type": "mousemove",
        "between": // ...
      },
      "update": "[selection1_x[0],scale(\"x\",datetime(year(invert(\"x\",clamp(x(unit),0,width))),0))]"
    },
    // ...
```

The lines are getting long, and this is without considering intervals smaller than a year. You probably don't want to write this stuff by hand!

#### smaller intervals

This method supports truncating to any of the parameters of the Vega [datetime expression](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#datetime):

> `datetime(year, month[, day, hour, min, sec, millisec])`
>   Returns a new `Date` instance. The month is 0-based, such that `1` represents February.

You have to specify at least year and month, so above we had zeros for month.

#### week

To snap to week, you can subtract the day of the week from the date of the month:

```
[selection1_x[0], scale("x", datetime(
    year(invert("x", clamp(x(unit),0,width))),
    month(invert("x", clamp(x(unit),0,width))),
    date(invert("x", clamp(x(unit),0,width)))
        - day(invert("x", clamp(x(unit),0,width)))))]
```

I haven't learned Vega well enough to know if I can simplify these expressions.

#### onward

Also vega-time is [in the pipeline](https://github.com/vega/vega/pull/2099), providing the functionality of [d3-time intervals](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#time-intervals-d3-time), so this should get a lot simpler in the near future!